# Find the average values by grouping and sub-grouping variables, and count of the number of times a value occurs within these groups in R

Tags: r, count, contingency

I have a dataset which has four columns of data.

I want to group the rows by two variables, and the columns by one variable

Here is an example of my data

```
df <- data.frame(
Price = rnorm(24), 
Grouping = rep(c("CD", "NW", "SMK", "ghd"),6),
Sub_grouping = c("CDapple", "NWapple", "SMKapple", "ghdapple",
               "CDPear", "NWpear", "SMKpear", "ghdpear",
               "CDgrape",  "NWgrape", "SMKgrape", "ghdgrape",
               "CDapple", "NWapple", "SMKapple", "ghdapple",
               "CDPear", "NWpear", "SMKpear", "ghdpear",
               "CDgrape",  "NWgrape", "SMKgrape", "ghdgrape"),
SP = rep(c("SP", "OffSP"),12))
```

To get the average of the Price variable for each subgroup, I can run the following:

```
df <- melt(df)
df_mean <- dcast(df, Grouping + Sub_grouping ~ SP, value.var = "value",  fun.aggregate = mean)
```

I would also like the average value of Price for each grouping variable. Is this possible?

I also would like to count the number of values for Price which feed into each average Price. So for each Group, by SP and OffSP, the number of prices which feed into this; and for each sub_group, by SP and OffSP, the number of prices which feed into this.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I've seen these questions [Create a column with a count of occurrences in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592041/create-a-column-with-a-count-of-occurrences-in-r)  [How can I count the number of instances a value occurs within a subgroup in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477232/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-instances-a-value-occurs-within-a-subgroup-in-r)
But their contingency tables are 2x2, and I need a table with grouping and sub-group as rows, with SP / OffSP as columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to reshape it to 'long' format to get the `mean` values

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Grouping) %>% #first grouping
   #create the mean column and the count by 'Grouping'
   mutate(AvgPrice = mean(Price), n1 = n()) %>% 
   group_by(Sub_grouping, add= TRUE) %>% #second grouping
   #summarise to get the mean within Sub_grouping and count the values with n()
   summarise(AvgPrice = first(AvgPrice), n1 = first(n1), AvgPrice2 = mean(Price), n2 = n())
```

NOTE: If we also need to group by 'SP', then change the first `group_by` statement to

```
df
  %>%
   group_by(Grouping, SP) %>%
   ...
   ...
```

---

If we want to get the `mean` and `length` for each 'SP' and wants as separate column, one compact option is `dcast` from `data.table` which can take multiple functions and multiple `value.var` columns

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Grouping + Sub_grouping ~ SP, value.var = "Price", c(mean, length))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea how to get the counts? Cheers.

Comment: @Laura Based on your description, do you need `SP` also as grouping variable

Comment: Yes please @akrun, if that's possible. Thank you.

Comment: @Laura In that case, just change the first group by, i.e. `df %>% group_by(Grouping, SP) %>% mutate(AvgPrice = mean(Price), n1 = n()) %>%  group_by(Sub_grouping, add= TRUE) %>%  summarise(AvgPrice = first(AvgPrice), n1 = first(n1), AvgPrice2 = mean(Price), n2 = n())`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much.

Comment: This is great, but the problem is that the grouping by SP still groups by row. I want to group by SP for the columns. So I'd end up with 8 additional columns: average value and count for Group and Subgroup by SP, and average value and count for Group and Subgroup by OffSP. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Thanks @akrun. When I run this code I get the following error message Error in .fun(.value[0], ...) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1

Comment: @Laura It is working fine with the example data you showed.  I am using `data.table_1.10.4`