# R programing inbuilt Titanic Data set

Tags: r

I am new to **R** programming. I have to build titanic data in R. I want to find out how many child and adults are there in the dataset. Can someone give me hint to find the same?

I tried using `length(`) function but it did not give the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477232/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-instances-a-value-occurs-within-a-subgroup-in-r

Comment: `?table` .......

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in tidyverse syntax. It converts the Titanic dataset into a tibble (a type of dataframe), groups the data by the `Age` column, then uses `n()` to count the number of rows at each level of `Age`, giving the number of children and adults.

```
library(tidyverse)

Titanic %>% 
   as_tibble() %>% 
   group_by(Age) %>% 
   summarise(N = n())
```

This gives the output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Age       N
  <chr> <int>
1 Adult    16
2 Child    16
```